# How to create a django ViewFlow process programmatically

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

*Synopsis*

I'm developing a web application to learn Django (python 3.4 & Django 1.6.10). The web app has complex and often updated workflows. I decided to integrate the Django-Viewflow library (https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/) as it seems to be a very convenient way to handle workflows and not incorporate the workflow logic with the application models.

In this case, I have created a workflow to collect authorship information and copyrights using the Django-Viewflow library. The workflow should be initiated each time an author is added to a book.

*My Problem*

The documentation offers step by step guidelines to integrate an end-to-end worklfow solution (frontend and backend). My problem is that I'm having hard time to control the workflow programmatically (specifically from the Book model).

*Description of the application*

I have a Book model (core model) with a many to many relationship to Authors.

**myApp/models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

The workflow components are:

**myFlow/models.py**

```
from viewflow.models import Process

class AuthorInvitation(process)     
    consent_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

**myFlow/flows.py**

```
from viewflow import flow
from viewflow.base import this, Flow
from viewflow.contrib import celery
from viewflow.views import StartProcessView, ProcessView
from . import models, tasks

class AuthorInvitationFlow(Flow):
    process_cls = models.AuthorInvitation

    start = flow.Start(StartProcessView) \
        .Permission(auto_create=True) \
        .Next(this.notify)

    notify = celery.Job(tasks.send_authorship_request) \
        .Next(this.approve)

    approve = flow.View(ProcessView, fields=["confirmed","signature"]) \
        .Permission(auto_create=True) \
        .Next(this.check_approve)

    check_approve = flow.If(cond=lambda p: p.confirmed) \
        .OnTrue(this.send) \
        .OnFalse(this.end)

    send = celery.Job(tasks.send_authorship) \
        .Next(this.end)

    end = flow.End()
```

*Question*

How can you control the workflow process programmatically (activate, confirm steps, redo steps, cancel the process....)? I have tried to dig into the code of the library. It seems that the `class activate` contains the right method but not sure how the whole should be orchestrated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two additional Start build-in Tasks available for Flows

StartFunction - starts flow when the function called somewhere:

```
@flow_start_func
def create_flow(activation, **kwargs):
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation

class FunctionFlow(Flow):
    start = flow.StartFunction(create_flow) \
        .Next(this.end)

# somewhere in the code
FunctionFlow.start.run(**some_kwargs)
```

StartSignal - starts flow on django signal receive:

```
class SignalFlow(Flow):
    start = flow.StartSignal(some_signal, create_flow) \      
        .Next(this.end)
```

You can check the usage for them, and rest of build-in task in [this viewflow  test suite](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/e3a34bd78c7a009a091c2600dfa3a9e797fb8964/tests/test_flow_signal.py).

For manually process the task state, first you should get the task from the database, activate it, and call any activation method.

```
task  = MyFlow.task_cls.objects.get(...)
activation = task.activate()
if  activation.undo.can_proceed():
    activation.undo()
```

Any activation transition have `.can_proceed()` method, helps you to check, is the task in the state that allows the transition.

Comment: The github link gives a 404, FWIW

Comment: AttributeError: 'StartFunction' object has no attribute 'prepare'

Comment: Yep, in latest version @flow_start_func decorator required in addition.

Comment: @kmmbvnr can I use django model post_save signal with StartSignal and how to implement it? I posted my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980834/viewflow-start-process-with-django-model-post-save-signal

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be able to manually or programmatically start a flow instance. The model I ended up with, based on the above reference to `StartFunction` looks like this:

```
class MyRunFlow(flow.Flow):
    process_class = Run

    start = flow.Start(ProcessCreate, fields=['schedule']). \
        Permission(auto_create=True). \
        Next(this.wait_data_collect_start)
    start2 = flow.StartFunction(process_create). \
        Next(this.wait_data_collect_start)
```

Note the important point is that `process_create` has the `Process` object and this code must programmatically set up the same fields that the manual form submission does via the fields specification to `ProcessCreate`:

```
@flow_start_func
def process_create(activation: FuncActivation, **kwargs):
    #
    # Update the database record.
    #
    db_sch = Schedule.objects.get(id=kwargs['schedule'])
    activation.process.schedule = db_sch # <<<< Same fields as ProcessCreate
    activation.process.save()
    #
    # Go!
    #
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation
```

Note that the `activation` subclass inside the `flow_start_func` is `FuncActivation`, which has the prepare() and save() methods. The `kwargs` come from the call to run, which goes something like:

```
start_node = <walk the flow class looking for nodes of type StartFunction>
activation = start_node.run(schedule=self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

to start manually:

```
from viewflow import flow
from viewflow.base import this, Flow
from .models import CIE
from viewflow import frontend
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@frontend.register
class CIE(Flow):
    process_class = CIE
    start = flow.StartFunction(this.create_flow).Next(this.end)
    end = flow.End()

    @method_decorator(flow.flow_start_func)
    def create_flow(self, activation):
        activation.prepare()
        activation.done()
        return activation
```

after that expose rpc:

```
from modernrpc.core import rpc_method
from flow.flows import CIE

    @rpc_method
    def start():
        CIE.start.run()
```