# How to define a unique URL and a custom template for a django ViewFlow Task

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

*Sysnopsis*

As mentioned in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734247/how-to-create-a-django-viewflow-process-programmatically) on stackoverflow, I'm implementing a workflow using [ViewFlow.io](http://viewflow.io/).

The use case is about collecting authorship information and copyrights using the Django-Viewflow library. The workflow should be initiated each time an author is added to a book.

**myFlow/flows.py**

```
from viewflow import flow
from viewflow.base import this, Flow
from viewflow.contrib import celery
from viewflow.views import StartProcessView, ProcessView
from . import models, tasks

class AuthorInvitationFlow(Flow):
    process_cls = models.AuthorInvitation

    start = flow.Start(StartProcessView) \
        .Permission(auto_create=True) \
        .Next(this.notify)

    notify = celery.Job(tasks.send_authorship_request) \
        .Next(this.approve)

    approve = flow.View(AuthorConfirmView) \
        .Permission(auto_create=True) \
        .Next(this.check_approve)

    check_approve = flow.If(cond=lambda p: p.confirmed) \
        .OnTrue(this.send) \
        .OnFalse(this.end)

    send = celery.Job(tasks.send_authorship) \
        .Next(this.end)

    end = flow.End()
```

***My problem***

1 - How can I specify a custom template for a specific task when creating a custom updateView?

Using template, or template_name does not work.

```
class AuthorConfirmView(TaskViewMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'template_1.html'
    fields = ["confirmed"]    

    def get_object(self):
        return self.activation.process
```

2- How/What is the best practice to have a unique url per process instance. When an author (aka user) visit a link of a process (workflow) instance (ex. http://mybook/process/11122), she will be redirected to the *active* task. Furthermore, I'm not sure whether or not "assign" is mandatory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yep, it's probably weird behavior and need to be fixed.

Currently TaskViewMixin searches for templates in the following way

```
return ('{}/{}/{}.html'.format(app_label, flow_label, flow_task.name),
        '{}/{}/task.html'.format(app_label, flow_label),
        'viewflow/flow/task.html')
```

2. In general case, workflow does not assume that the only one active task available at the moment of time. But when you select somehow the right task instance, you can call the get_task_url method

   task.flow_task.get_task_url(task, url_type='guess', user=request.user)

You can check the `viewflow.views.base.get_task_url` for details how redirection on next active task is implemented in the task view.

Assign is mandatory, as you can see in the diagram of states for the flow Task() in the [documentation](http://docs.viewflow.io). This prevent concurrent task execution by different users. In other case two users could start the same task, but only one will be able to save its work.

You can implement custom activation class, with different states, or you can assign task to the user automatically, by adding .Assign(lambda process: return_some_user()) to your task declaration