# How to start a Flow with user subscription

Tags: django, workflow, django-allauth, django-viewflow

We are using Django-allauth for user subscription management with an optional email confirmation and few social provider (facebook, google, etc).
We wanted to start a flow when the confirmation email in sent.

The entire flow doesn't use views as it just sends emails to convince new users to complete their profile.

The StartView seems to be required in Flows, and I don't understand how to activate the flow without a view.

Comment: that was already posted, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734247/how-to-create-a-django-viewflow-process-programmatically