# Django viewflow Get flow in shell?

Tags: django-viewflow

Thanks to author project for this beautiful and helpful app, but I'm a novice and all work fine from demo frontend and nothing from the django code...so I kindly ask you: how the flow can be managed without frontend:

```
x, created =TestProcess.objects.get_or_create()
Out[1]: (<TestProcess: <Process 19> - NEW>, True)
```

# The process exist

```
In [12]: x.status
Out[12]: 'NEW'
```

# the status is correct

```
x.task_set.exists
Out[23]: <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0x7f0d917c1438>>
```

In my flow I've put:

```
class HellxoWorldFlow(Flow):
    start = (
        flow.Start(
            flow_views.CreateProcessView,
            fields=['text', 'wo_rif'],
            task_title=_('Start'))
        .Permission(auto_create=True)
        .Next(this.secondstep)
    )
```

but x.flow_class seems to be '', and  a "x.next_flow_step" doesn't exist, how can I get the next step for this process?
Thanks, BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the `.objects.get_or_create()` call, that makes an empty process model, not attached to any flow class.

If you would like to start a flow programmatically, you need to use `flow.StartFunction`

You can check this answer for details - [How to create a django ViewFlow process programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734247/how-to-create-a-django-viewflow-process-programmatically)