# How to jump to the middle of the flow in ViewFlow?

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I'm using ViewFlow/Django and I've defined Flow which includes 10 steps.

Suppose I have all the relevant data for the first 5 steps.

How can I programatically start my flow, save the data for these steps and jump directly to step 6?

The problem is that I have the flow working with the frontend but now I want to do the first 5 steps from the API. I added this to my flow:

class MyFlow(Flow):

```
@method_decorator(flow_start_func)
def create_request(self, activation, **kwargs):
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation

start_from_code = StartFunction(this.create_request). \
    Next(this.my_first_step_in_a_flow)
```

but I'm doing something wrong, since when I try to run with:

```
MainOnBoardingFlow.start_from_code.run()
```

i get NotImplementedError

Comment: See [the bit about processing task state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736975/9043116), but watch out for [exception handling issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243607/configure-viewflow-io-error-handling-model).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to skip. Just add second start node connected to the middle of yours flow. It could be [StartFunction](http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_flow_nodes.html#viewflow.flow.StartFunction) where you would pass prepared data

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to move on my flow step by step programatically, with giving the relevant data each time, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The question, as phrased, can be interpreted in two ways:

1. When the idea is to **start** a brand new Viewflow process. This is the
   interpretation answered by @kmmbvnr using the `StartFunction` node. A
   fuller answer is at [How to create a django ViewFlow process programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734247/how-to-create-a-django-viewflow-process-programmatically).
2. When the idea is to **continue** an existing Viewflow process at a given
   Task (presumably at a View node Task). In the latter case, the key is to
   use the `Function` node. In my case, I had the following View and the
   corresponding Function:

```py
class MyFlow(Flow):
    approve_run_as_payroll_approver = flow.View(
        ProcessApproval, form_class=ProcessApproval.Form). \
        Permission(). \
        Assign(). \
        Next(this.check_pay_run_approved)
    approve_run_as_payroll_approver_fn = flow.Function(process_approve). \
        Next(this.check_pay_run_approved)
```

The `process_approve` handler is decorated like this:

```py
@flow_func
def process_approve(activation: FuncActivation, *, approved, **kwargs):
   ...
```

The process is resumed as follows:

```py
   task = myproecss.active_tasks().get(...)
   MyFlow.approve_run_as_payroll_approver_fn.run(..., task=task, ...)
```

see the documentation for the arguments.