# Viewflow - start process with Django model post_save signal

Tags: django, django-signals, django-viewflow

Is there a way to start a Viewflow process with Django model post_save signal. I managed to do this:

```
//start viewflow process
start = (
    flow.StartSignal(post_save, create_dest_flow)
        .Next(this.approve)
)

//create flow function
def create_dest_flow(**kwargs):
   print("Test")
   pass
```

The "Test" string is printed for every save on any model. If I add activation to the create flow function parameteres I get an error: **missing 1 required positional argument: 'activation'**.
How to start the flow **only on specific model post_save** signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed `@flow_start_signal` decorator

http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.StartSignal